# Run-Time Error 1004: MS Excel is refreshing some data. Please try again later using Query

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have a dynamic query in a sheet that uses a parameter in cell C1. So, In column A there are codes, and in column B are those code descriptions and based on the value in cell C1, the query will refresh to display codes related to the value in C1. When the value in C1 changes, I get a "Run-Time Error 1004: MS Excel is refreshing some data. Please try again later", every time. When I select "End" it goes away and refreshes the query successfully, after a couple seconds, Does anyone know the reason behind this? Can I get rid of it?

[image]

There is a search feature. when the user clicks "Search" to search for the codes they're looking for, the search button is assigned a macro that essentially just navigates to the sheet which displays the codes. However, in that macro, I added this bit of code:

`Sheets("department_lookup").Cells(1, 3).Value = Sheets("lookup").Cells(2, 2).Value 
    With Sheets("department_lookup") .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC)).AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=.Cells(1, 3).Value, VisibleDropDown:=True End With`

Comment: `based on the value in cell C1, the query will refresh to display codes related to the value in C1` How are you achieving that? User Defined Function or Event triggered Sub?

Comment: @bulbus There is a search feature. when the user click "Search" to search for the codes they're looking for, the search button is assigned a macro that essentially just navigates to the sheet which displays the codes. In that macro, I added this bit of code: `Sheets("department_lookup").Cells(1, 3).Value = Sheets("lookup").Cells(2, 2).Value
With Sheets("department_lookup")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC)).AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=.Cells(1, 3).Value, VisibleDropDown:=True
End With`

Comment: (Can you edit that code in to your main post, and format as code? It's hard to read in the comments).

Comment: I suspect the button for some reason is getting called twice... Check if the [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f942f0e2-3daf-4a06-a7c9-3904a88e49bc/macro-called-twice-on-single-button-click?forum=isvvba) helps... In short put a `MsgBox` and see if 
 the click event is getting called before the query finishes running.

Answer (score 2):

I found this occurs when you are using a combination of Excel native queries and VBA DB code. For me, I found I couldn't access the database using an OLEDBConnection when Excel was refreshing using it's native refresh function.

**SOLUTION:**
I had to turn `BackgroundQuery = False` on the native queries. 
(This can be done from the Query properties using the GUI)

**EXPLANATION:**
BackgroundQuery allows you to use the spreadsheet while it is refreshing data. This is okay for a user who wants to use a spreadsheet but not for a VBA macro that wants to talk to that same database. When set to false it causes Excel to hang during a refresh. This stops your operations from colliding.

If this isn't your exact scenario look for similar collisions where 2 queries are stepping upon eachother.

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who knows a little bit about ODBC, from Excel, go to `Data` tab. Click on `Queries & Connections`. Then, right-click each connection tile, click `Properties`. Under usage, untick `Enable background refresh`. That should do the trick. At least, for me, that worked. :D